# cross origin domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to access a PHP file which is located in my domain but I want to do that using AJAX with jQuery. I am using a localhost and from there I am trying to call the PHP file here is the code I am using:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#callAjax").click(function() {
            var theName = $.trim($("#theName").val());
            if(theName.length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "http://studiofutbol.com.ec/upload_file.php",
                  data: ({name: theName}),
                  cache: false,
                  dataType: "text",
                  success: onSuccess
                });
            }
        });

        $("#resultLog").ajaxError(function(event, request, settings, exception) {
          $("#resultLog").html("Error Calling: " + settings.url + "<br />HTPP Code: " +     request.status);
        });

        function onSuccess(data)
        {
            $("#resultLog").html("Result: " + data);
                $('#people_list').append("hola");
                $('#people_list').listview('ref resh');
        }
    });
</script>
```

But I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://studiofutbol.com.ec/upload_file.php. Origin  http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [About same origin policy....Can I do this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163162/about-same-origin-policy-can-i-do-this)

Comment: you can't post date cross domain

Comment: @Dau — Yes, you can. You just can't read the response in old browsers.

Comment: @Dau, Sure you can.  Create a form element, set the method attribute to POST, set the action attribute to any URL you like, and call the `submit` method.

Comment: but if the url is from another domain i get the error, and how i do that with ajax thanks

Comment: i prefer use json for allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. but i dunno for post, i usually use get. google it for more

Answer (score 0):

Put this code on you php page (http://studiofutbol.com.ec/upload_file.php) for autorize Cross-domain comunication with $.ajax

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>
```

Hope it's help you !